# iPhone style select box wheel plugin for desktop

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, forms, select

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that can present a select box in an iphone-style wheel, stacking the options on top of each other with the ability to use your mouse to scroll through the options.

Does any one know of any plugins that could achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I found the perfect solution, here it is for anyone else who'd like it http://mobiscroll.com/

Comment: Don't be sorry, answering your own question is totally fine.

Comment: It is very costly